# Openerp, how to make a unique record

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo

I am currently working with `hr_holidays` (aka `Leave Management`) Module and I need to add leave allocation as a unique record for given type of leave.

I have added one extra condition in the `create()` function and that result in  not allowing any making leave request to be made.

Following is my `create()` function:

```
 def create(self, cr, uid, values, context=None):

    #-------what I have added starting from here------

    hol_stat=values['holiday_status_id']
    emp_id=values['employee_id']
    n_allo=values['test_allocation']

    ids=self.pool.get('hr.holidays').search(cr, uid, [('holiday_status_id','=', hol_stat),('employee_id','=', emp_id),('type','=','add')], context=context)
        if ids:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_('Already allocated leaves .'))
    # ------end from here-----


        """ Override to avoid automatic logging of creation """
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        context = dict(context, mail_create_nolog=True)

        if ('date_from' in values and 'date_to' in values):
            define_holidays = self.pool.get('company.holidays').search(cr, uid, ['|',('date', '=', values['date_from']),('date', '=', values['date_to'])])

            if define_holidays:
                raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning!'),_('You need not to apply leaves one Company holidays.'))
            else: 
                return super(hr_holidays, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
        else:#mani
            return super(hr_holidays, self).create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
```

**Question**

How can I alter my `create()` function to achieve the unique record requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing a search anytime you want to create a new record, enforce a `UniqueConstraint` on the database, that wouldn't allow duplicate records to be created, with this

```
_sql_constraints = [
        ('unique_hol_empid_type', 'unique(holiday_status_id, employee_id, type)', 'Error: Already allocated leaves'),
    ]
```

the unique constraint is a combination of the three columns you want, and `unique_hol_empid_type` is the name we gave to the constraint (at the database layer) and the error will be raised anytime a record violates that constraint.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...it would work on any database new or old, provided that no record in the db violates the constraint